# Is my code Jquery or AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I heard that AJAX use xml concept. But I had some doubt that whether the following code is JQUERY or AJAX. Find it for me. Give me differences between Jquery and AJAX

```
$(".changepass").click(function() {
   $(".loading").show();
   $(".block1").load("views/changepass.template.php", function(){ $(".loading").hide(); });
   return false;
 }
```

Comment: google and wiki both dead?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX & http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery

Comment: Sometimes is nice to have an exact answer to the specific question you asked. I don't think that warranted a down vote.

Comment: I can see how this would be confusing for beginners

Comment: I don't think that warranted a down vote, but I don't think that it warranted an up vote either.

Comment: @voyager people who downvote beginners like this think they are punishing them for asking a bad question, but the pity votes ALWAYS come in, so it's almost always a win for the asker.  After all, it only takes 1 up vote to cancel out 5 down votes (in terms of rep).    The best thing to do is to leave it at 0...

Comment: +1 for asking wanting to learn. This dude will make the web a better place someday

Comment: "Find it for me" isn't really a question, it's a demand.  I think that'd warrant a downvote.  This isn't a "I want to learn, please point me in the right direction" question.  It clearly says "Find it for me. Give me differences ..."  It's rather rude.

Comment: @doomspork im Just now learning english too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is in jQuery and is used to load HTML from a remote file and inject it into the DOM. In this case you are injecting the HTML to an element with class 'block1'.

```
$(".changepass").click
```

> attaches a clink event to element with
>   class 'changepass'

See [**click**](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click)

```
$(".loading").show();
```

> show an element with class 'loading'

See [**show**](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/show)

```
$(".block1").load
```

> loads an HTML to element with class
>   'block1' using AJAX.

See [**load**](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load)

Answer (score 11):

jQuery is a JavaScript library. AJAX, which means Asynchronous JavaScript and XML is a technique.

AJAX is...

> used on the client-side to create interactive web applications or rich Internet applications. With Ajax, web applications can retrieve data from the server asynchronously in the background without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page.

The `$(<selector>)` notation you are using is using the jQuery library. You can learn more about jQuery by visiting [the site](http://jquery.com/).

The `.load()` method in your code uses AJAX to *asynchronously* load whatever is being return by that PHP function to the `$(<selector>)`.

Source (added from voyager's comment):
[Jquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jquery)
[Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))

Comment: For clarity, I would probably say $(<selector>)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is a javascript library. It's especially useful because it uses CSS3 selectors (the query part) to find elements on the page, and so is quite powerful with minimal syntax.

AJAX stands for *Asynchronous Javascript and Xml*. Originally AJAX implementations used the XmlHttp ActiveX components Microsoft provided for web based Outlook access. Later browsers (FX, IE6 and above, everything else) included it as a built in component.

However XmlHttp methods that AJAX uses can fit above any HTTP call, and so many calls use JSON or HTML instead. So ajax now means any asynchronous javascript method that calls the server.

jQuery includes an Ajax library, as do most Javascript frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a Javascript library. AJAX is a combination of XML, Javascript and the HTTP request.

The code you're showing here is obviously jQuery, and thus, Javascript. Certainly no AJAX, as it is *not* a language.

Comment: Ajax does not have to use xml.

Comment: True, but it's what the name stands for. It actually isn't even necessarily Javascript, not even necessarily asynchronous ;-) So, for the sake of simplicity, I put it this way. Sharp, though, so +1!

Comment: There is AJAX in his code becuase he's using the .load() command which uses the XMLHTTPRequest object

Answer (score 0):

Your code is jQuery.

Read about jQuery here: [link text](http://jQuery.com)

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is a collection of technologies that enable richer user experience to the web application users by providing ways to send request to the web server "in the background" (asynchronous - A part of ajax) and update part of a page instead of refreshing the whole page. 
JQUERY is just a framework that helps you implement AJAX features in your web application.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of them.

because code and development technique are uncomparable
because your code does not look like [this](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js)

For more info check other answers. Should be enough. :)